# How can I draw a model perpendicular to a sloped surface?

Tags: geometry, matrix, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find rotation in 3D based on a vector/normal?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-find-rotation-in-3d-based-on-a-vector-normal)

My models are axis-aligned. I know the normal of the surface I want to draw them on.

How do I compute the rotations or rotation matrix that I should use to draw the model perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: Might I point you to this question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-find-rotation-in-3d-based-on-a-vector-normal/6139

Comment: And to your own? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740434/drawing-a-model-on-a-slope

Comment: -1, please don't cross post.

Comment: at least I got any kind of answer there.

Comment: You didn't get an answer here because your question was a duplicate of an existing one, and because people here tend not to answer questions posted on SO also.

Comment: No Joe, I posted to SO because I didn't see any activity here.  In fact, I generally note that SO is a better place for getting answers as a hobby games programmer.

Comment: You were also given a possible duplicate question with an accepted answer to your request. If you feel that way, I suggest you use SO, but questions are starting to be migrated here more frequently from SO that refer to games dev. Just something to think about.